# ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string to char

Tags: c++

From what I read here, you can't do :

```
char *delegates[]={"IN",NULL};
```

it has to be this so you do not get a warning :

```
const char *delegates[]={"IN",NULL};
```

But I have some function that **I can't change** that looks like :

```
void Interpreter::setBuiltIns(char *builtins[],int num  )
```

This function is not going to change the array in any way.

If I try to pass it the strings array with :

```
myclass.setBuiltIns(delegates, 1);
```

I get an error, but if I **remove** the `const` from `delegate` there is no error but I get the `ISO warning` .

How can I keep this function, and pass it the array without a warning/error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends. If it is **guaranteed** that `setBuiltIns` does not modify the strings, you can just `const_cast` the `const` away.

Otherwise, choose the always safe path and copy the literals into new buffers.

---

As requested, an example for the first variant:

```
void fun(char *builtins[]){}

int main () {
    const char *delegates[] = {"IN",nullptr};
    fun(const_cast<char **>(delegates));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also cast string literals to 'char*' in your array initializer.

```
void fun(char *builtins[]){}

int main() {
    char *delegates2[] = {(char*)"IN",nullptr};
    fun(delegates2);
}
```